# shift first index value as array key

Tags: php, arrays

Using `array_map` and exploding `stdclass object` following output can be provided(**No.1**).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2@@@10
            [1] => 4@@@1
            [2] => 5@@@0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2@@@30
            [1] => 4@@@30
        )
)
```

Now, I need to explode through `@@@` and shift first index value as key, not creating another level of subarray

Expected Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2] => 10
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => 30
            [4] => 30
        )
)
```

Data is fetched from server as this way

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hdng] => 2@@@10***4@@@1***5@@@0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hdng] => 2@@@30***4@@@30
        )
)
```

I extract array from `stdclass Object` exploding through `***` and using `array_map` to return. Result is output(**No.1**), But I don't need another subarray, just wanna shift.

```
$newArr = array_map(function($data){
    $arr = explode('***',$data->hdng);
    return $arr;
}, $data);
```

Comment: So have you actually tried to perform this task? It seems relatively straightforward; instead of directly returning the result of explode, reformat to what you need and return that.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each array $arr element inner array_map callback function and then explode again using "@@@" delimiter.

```
$newArr = array_map(function($data) {
    $arr = array();
      
    foreach(explode('***', $data->hdng) as $s) {
        list($key, $value) = explode("@@@", $s);
        $arr[$key] = $value;
    }
    
    return $arr;
}, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$newArr= array_map(function($data->hdng){
    preg_match_all('/([\d]+)@{3}([\d]+)\*{0,3}/i', $data,$match,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    array_map(function($data) use (&$arr){
        return $arr[$data[1]]=$data[2];
    }, $match);
    return $arr;
}, $data);
print_r($newArr);
```

out put

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [2] => 10 [4] => 1 [5] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [2] => 30 [4] => 30 ) )
```